# how to apply yapf to every python file under a directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yapf

I have installed Google yapf (yet another python formatter) under a project and try to format all my python files in-place, however I got the following error:

```
$ yapf -i -r files **.py
yapf: Input filenames did not match any python files
```

why yapf is incapable of understanding pattern? What should I do to achieve the same thing?

**EDIT** I also tried yapf -ir as suggested but I got:

```
$ yapf -ir
usage: yapf [-h] [-v] [-d | -i] [-r | -l START-END] [-e PATTERN]
            [--style STYLE] [--style-help] [--no-local-style] [-p] [-vv]
            [files [files ...]]
yapf: error: cannot use --in-place or --diff flags when reading from stdin
```

which is strange as I'm not reading from stdin

Comment: That's not what I suggested...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The first problem is that wildcard expansion happens in the shell, *before* the command line even executes.  When you run:

```
somecommand *.py
```

That command doesn't know you typed a `*`.  All it knows is that you passed in a list of files.  In other words, `yapf` is incapable of understanding the pattern because it never *sees* the pattern.

The second problem is that `**` isn't a valid shell file globbing pattern.  That's semantically equivalent to `*`, so running `yapf -ir files **.py` will only process any `.py` files contained in your current directory and inside the `files` directory.

If you want to run `yapf` recursively on all your Python files, starting in your current directory, there are a few solutions. The simplest is probably:

```
yapf -ir .
```

This will process all `.py` files in your current directory and its children.  If you want more control over the selection of files, use `find` and `xargs`:

```
find . -name '*.py' -print0 | xargs -0 yapf -i
```

Comment: thanks a lot, the second command works properly, the first one doesn't, as I have shown in my question update.

Comment: You forgot the `.` in the command in your example. Since you didn't pass `yapf` a list of files, it thinks you're trying to process Python input on stdin.